# How to know when user dismisses Share option in React Native

Tags: react-native

I am building an app with Expo that utilizes RN's [Share API](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/share.html) feature. I have successfully implemented the following to share an image:

```
Share.share(
{
  message: 'This is a message',
  url: FileSystem.documentDirectory + imageUrlDate
},
{
  dialogTitle: 'Share Today',
  excludedActivityTypes: [
    'com.apple.mobilenotes.SharingExtension',
    'com.apple.reminders.RemindersEditorExtension'
  ]
}
```

);

What I would like to know is how to use the [sharedAction()](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/share.html#sharedaction) and [dismissedAction()](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/share.html#dismissedaction) options.

Basically, I want to know whether a user cancels sharing or follows through.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you can read from the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/share.html#share), `Share.share()` returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and the return action shows you if the user shared or dismissed the dialog. Dismissed action **is only for iOS** so you might need to write [platform specific code](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/platform-specific-code.html#platform-specific-code) if your implementation needs.

> **In iOS**, Returns a Promise which will be invoked an object containing
>   action, activityType. If the user dismissed the dialog, the Promise
>   will still be resolved with action being Share.dismissedAction and all
>   the other keys being undefined.
>
> **In Android**, Returns a Promise which always be resolved with action
>   being Share.sharedAction.

So you can do something like this,

```
Share.share({ message: 'This is a message', url: FileSystem.documentDirectory + imageUrlDate },
{
  dialogTitle: 'Share Today',
  excludedActivityTypes: [
    'com.apple.mobilenotes.SharingExtension',
    'com.apple.reminders.RemindersEditorExtension'
  ]
}).then(({action, activityType}) => {
  if(action === Share.dismissedAction) console.log('Share dismissed');
  else console.log('Share successful');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

bennygenels answer is mostly correct but share() returns a Promise which [resolves as an object](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/eb0d6470e54663538610a70ab0bae9847eb33673/Libraries/Share/Share.js#L94), so we need some extra curly braces {} to make it actually work:

```
Share.share({ message: 'This is a message', url: FileSystem.documentDirectory + imageUrlDate },
{
  dialogTitle: 'Share Today',
  excludedActivityTypes: [
    'com.apple.mobilenotes.SharingExtension',
    'com.apple.reminders.RemindersEditorExtension'
  ]
}).then(({action, activityType}) => {
  if(action === Share.dismissedAction) console.log('Share dismissed');
  else console.log('Share successful');
});
```

Comment: Add some details to your answer.